# Detect whether Japanese IME is active in input box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ime

Is there a way to detect whether a Japanese (or other language) input method editor is active when a user is typing into an input box in Javascript? I have an input box which responds to the enter key to submit a form, but while testing with a Japanese IME I realized that the user might press enter to confirm an autocomplete candidate, which still triggers my own code.

Essentially, while typing autocomplete suggestions appear, and I'd only like the enter key to trigger a form submission when the IME has completely finished its work. I do see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionend_event, which looks like I could use `compositionstart` and `compositionend` events to set a boolean, and then check the boolean when the user hits enter; I'm just curious if there's a way to directly query whether the IME is active, as I'm slightly worried that handling the state manually might turn out to be brittle if it's possible for things to become out of sync.

EDIT: So I have found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/isComposing, which can be used to check if the keypress event is fired within the context of the IME, but the last Enter which causes the `compositionend` event to fire doesn't have isComposing set, so setting a boolean has been the only thing I've found that works. However, there is a race condition, where depending on whether the `keypress` or `compositionend` event handler goes first the code may still erroneously cause the enter which causes the IME to exit to trigger the input submission. The only way around this I've found was to introduce an asyncronous delay in the `onCompositionEnd` event handler, to ensure that it always goes last.

That way, when hitting Enter in the IME, the `isIME` boolean is true, and the `keypress` event finishes first, checking the `isIME` boolean and finishing without submitting the answer, then the `onCompositionEnd` finishes and sets the `isIME` boolean to false. The non-determinism isn't great, but this seems to be working.

Comment: I have no experience with IME and never knew it existed until reading this however I would suspect that some boolean property is set somewhere in window global or window.navigator or similar when it has been activated in OS

Comment: I'm not even sure if the property would be window specific, or local to each input box. My main worry is if it's possible for multiple IMEs to exist in different input fields, causing my own code to get confused which events correspond to which input box. Assuming everything is isolated to each input box then having each one respond to their own events and set their own boolean should solve the issue.
I'm just very new to Javascript, so I don't know if that's how things actually work, or just how I want them to work. My current solution does work, I just don't know that it's future proof.

Comment: That must depend on the OS, on my macOS, when the compositionend event fires there is no keypress event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an input box which responds to the enter key to submit a form

Just don't do that. Put your `<input>` element inside the `<form>`, and have your code respond to the form's `submit` event instead of specific key events. Pressing enter in a normal input will already select an autocomplete candidate or submit the form - but not both - by default.

Comment: That was exactly my issue as it turns out, and fixed it perfectly. Thank you.